# C# Diaglog Box/About Box

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make my about box appear, but it just gives me an error message of, "CS0120/An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.ShowDialog()".

I created a About Box under Project/New Item and named my About box, 'About'. Super simple.

And my code for my button:

```
About.ShowDialog();
```

I mean, there shouldn't be anything else I would need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
About about = new About();
about.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The message that "an object reference is required" should be a clue that you need to allocate an object.